# CSV with Semi-Colon as delimiter

Tags: csv, peoplesoft

Has anyone ever written peoplecode to read a CSV file that uses semi-colons as a delimiter and comma as a decimal divider?

I need to read an Italian CSV file that uses those characters instead of the normal comma and decimal point.

What was your experience?  Anything to watch out for?

Answer (score 1):

Two options, one using file layout and the other without.

Option A) Using file layout: Consider below properties of filelayout

1. Definition Delimiter = "semicolon"
2. FieldType for the numeric field having comma as decimal divider = "character"
3. After reading the field, replace comma with a period and use `value(&new_str)` on the new string to convert it to number

Option B) Without file layout:

1. Open the input file in your code.
2. Loop through each line.
3. Use split to fetch field values- e.g.
   `&ret_arr = split(&str_line,";");`
4. `&ret_arr` array will be populated with field values, access them using `&ret_arr[1],..[2]` etc.
5. Replace comma from that numeric field and use `value(&new_str)` for conversion.

Above was my experience (long back), nothing else to watch out for. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a file layout it probably won't read the commas in as decimal separator although you can tell it to use the semi-colon as the separator.  Your other option is to read all fields in as text and then do a replace on the number fields to replace the comma with a period and then do a value() on the string to convert it to a number.